# awk Extract Text Nth Occurrence Square Brackets (Containing Line Break In File Text)

Tags: regex, awk

I have 0.txt and 1.txt files. In the 0.txt file the content is as shown below:

```
[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}][{G,H,I}]
```

The contents of the 1.txt file is as shown below:

```
[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}]
[{G,H,I}]
```

That is, the difference between 0.txt and 1.txt is that in the 1.txt file there is a line break.

What I desire is to be able to extract all the text between **'['** and **']'** in your **NTH OCCURRENCE** using `awk -F'[][]' -v n=2 '{ print $(2*n) }' 1.txt > 2.txt` ([Extract the text between the nth occurrence of square brackets](https://www.unix.com/302820195-post2.html)), this for text formatting shown in **1.txt** file.

So my wishes corresponding to n=2 would be 2.txt as shown below:

`{G,H,I}`

To do so, at first, I have been able to do this just for text formatting when there is no line break as shown at **0.txt**.

I need to know how to extract the text between **'['** and **']'** when there is line break as shown at **1.txt**.

The output of `awk -F'[][]' -v n=2 '{ print $(2*n) }' 1.txt > 2.txt` has been all the content of 0.txt (except Square Brackets) instead of only `{G,H,I}`. That is, the 2.txt content is as below:

```
{A,B,C},{D,E,F}
{G,H,I}
```

**Edit Update 01:**

The solution must have the same effect for a third input file as below, considering the third occurrence, that is, `[{J, K, L}]`. So the expected exit should be `{J, K, L}`.

```
[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}]
[{G,H,I}]
[{J,K,L}]
```

For all purposes for the nth occurrence of `[{x, y, z, ..}]` (respected the condition of no text out of **[** and **]**, and no blank line) Any solution given should extract to the Output file exactly `{x, y, z, ..}`.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts and Good post(keep it up), could you please post sample of expected output too in your question more little more clarity of it, thank you.

Comment: `-F'[][]'` doesn't actually find text between `[` and `]`. e.g. `awk -F'[][]' -v n=1 '{ print $(n*2) }' <<< '[abc'` will print `abc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to extract the text between `[` and `]` with the given record number

You may try this `gnu-awk` command that will work irrespective of presence of line break between bracket pairs

```sh
awk -v n=2 -v RS='\\[[^]]*]' 'RT && NR == n {print substr(RT, 2, length(RT)-2)}' file

{G,H,I}
```

Since we are using custom `RS` of `[...]` it will print correct record no matter if 2nd pair of `[...]` is in first line or second line.

Comment: `awk -v n=3 -v RS='\\[[^]]*]' 'RT && NR == n {print substr(RT, 2, length(RT)-2)}' <<< '[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}][{G,H,I}][aaa]'` will print `aaa`

Comment: Sorry, I posted Ed Morton solution.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^][\n]+' -v RS='^$' -v n=2 '{print $n}' 0.txt
{G,H,I}

$ awk -v FPAT='[^][\n]+' -v RS='^$' -v n=2 '{print $n}' 1.txt
{G,H,I}
```

With any awk and assuming you don't have any blank lines in the input:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F '][[:space:]]*[[]|^[[]|]$' -v n=2 '{print $(n+1)}' 0.txt
{G,H,I}

$ awk -v RS= -F '][[:space:]]*[[]|^[[]|]$' -v n=2 '{print $(n+1)}' 1.txt
{G,H,I}
```

Comment: This has not worked for a third occurrence.

Comment: Without seeing the input where it failed and with just "this has not worked" as the symptoms I'm sorry but I've no idea how to debug that. All I can tell you is that it works for the sample input/output you provided in your question and will work for any similar input.

Comment: i am using `awk -v FPAT='[^][\n]+' -v RS='^$' -v n=3 '{print $2}' 0.txt`, where 0.txt is `[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}] \n
[{G,H,I}] \n
[{J,K,L}]` (where `\n` is line break, without line blanks) but given output `{G,H,I}`.

Comment: `awk -v RS= -F '][[:space:]]*[[]|^[[]|]$' -v n=3 '{print $(n+1)}' 0.txt` It worked for n=3.

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM in the gawk script you're printing `$2`, not `$n`. When I very first posted the script it did that but I quickly fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate approach assuming your input doesn't have any non-newline characters outside of `[]` delimiters. This will work with any `awk`.

```sh
$ tr '[]' '\n' <ip.txt | awk -v RS= -v ORS= 'NR==2'
{G,H,I}
```

The `tr` command will replace all `[]` characters with newline characters. The `awk` command uses 2 or more consecutive newlines as record separator. Any excess newlines at the beginning of the input will be ignored. So, you can now just use the record number to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

If you preprocess the data with `grep`, the extraction becomes trivial, e.g.:

```
n=3
<0.txt grep -oE '\{[^}]+\}' | sed -n ${n}p
<1.txt grep -oE '\{[^}]+\}' | sed -n ${n}p
```

Output :

```
{G,H,I}
{G,H,I}
```

#### Edit - Change in OPs requirements

If what you want is the contents of the square-brackets, then a minor change to this solution would still work, e.g.:

```
n=3
<new.txt grep -oE '\[[^]]+\]' | tr -d '[]' | sed -n ${n}p
```

Output:

```
{J,K,L}
```

Comment: i am Using your script as a file.sh, where 0.txt is `[{A,B,C},{D,E,F}] \n [{G,H,I}] \n [{J,K,L}]` (where `\n` is line break, without line blanks) but given output `{G,H,I}` when running file.sh instead of the `{J,K,L}`. Note: i say to n=3 how is in your script .

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM: change `n=3` to `n=4`?

Comment: I finally ended up not doing this, your solution worked with n=4, sorry :)

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM: if you use square-brackets in the regular expression, you can still use this solution, see edit.